# Not Able To Push Theme App Extension Code On Shop With Shopify CLI 3.X Commands

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am creating shopify custom app. For front end changes using theme app extensions. extensions was working with shopify CLI 2.x but shopify updated shopify CLI 2.x to CLI 3.x. I have updated shpify CLI 3.x but now i am pushing extensions code with shopify CLI 3.x facing below issue on commands:

```
2023-06-06 17:49:16 │ webhooks │ Sending APP_UNINSTALLED webhook to app server
2023-06-06 17:49:16 │ webhooks │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
2023-06-06 17:49:21 │ webhooks │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
2023-06-06 17:49:26 │ webhooks │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
2023-06-06 17:49:31 │ webhooks │ App hasn't started in time, giving up
2023-06-06 17:49:31 │ webhooks │ APP_UNINSTALLED webhook delivery failed
```

Please suggest me with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do what I do. Ignore that webhook information. It is known to be a Shopify workaround that has no real effect on anything, so at the end of the day, your theme app extension code has been deployed. If you do want to clean up that messaging though, just spend a few minutes and implement a NOOP webhook handler for that incoming webhook. You probably want it anyway, so no harm there.

Comment: I am facing some Jquery issue in theme app extensions on front end like

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I have include jquery library in  app-block.liquid file

<script src="{{ 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' | asset_url }}" defer></script>
Please let me know  where i am doing wrong

Comment: for more details see here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464846/jquery-is-not-defined-in-front-end-by-app-extensions-in-shopify

Comment: You probably forgot to add jQuery to your asset folder. Also, you should avoid fat libraries like jQuery and for your extension just write JS. Fat libraries will slow your extension down, and slow is bad. Slow will punish you.

Comment: I have added library into extensions assets folder, still not working.