# jQuery is not defined in front end by app-extensions in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am working on custom shopify app and using app extensions for front code like including js library but facing some issue

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I am including jquery library in app-block.liquid of app extensions. I have downloaded jquery library into assets folder using below code for include library.

```
<script src="{{ 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' | asset_url }}" defer></script>
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong

Comment: You are spamming this question now? Have you tried waiting for your precious jQuery library to be downloaded before you try and use it? The defer option does not mean it is available until DOMContentLoaded is true. Are you checking that?